# Unable to change setting in iOS 8

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios, xcode

I have developed my application using mobilesdk 2.2. Everything was working fine before I have upgraded my xCode to 6.0. After upgrade when I change my app setting environment to 'sandbox' or 'custom host'  it reset automatically to production.

Has someone face this issue?

I am hesitating in release build with newer sdk, Can someone help me on this?

-Manish kumar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about using the simulator and it not taking your SFDCOAuthLoginHost value, take a look at this GitHub issue. It looks like the simulator isn't picking up the value correctly, but if you hook up your actual device it works fine. A bit inconvenient to develop with, but sounds like your only option.

https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/issues/688

**UPDATE**

Per a response in this issue, in your iOS Simulator you can choose **Reset Content and Settings**. That worked for me.

https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/issues/755

Comment: I have tried reset but it doesn't work